# Unable to bootstrap Elasticsearch v7.4.0 3 node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, java-11, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I'm setting up ES v7.4.0 and below are my settings.

```
cluster.name: prod-elk-logging-7-4-0
node.name: "prod-elk-master1-new"
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: "prod-elk-master1-new"
discovery.seed_hosts: ["prod-elk-master1-new", "prod-elk-master2-new", "prod-elk-master3-new"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["prod-elk-master1-new", "prod-elk-master2-new", "prod-elk-master3-new"]
node.master: true
node.ml: false
node.ingest: false
node.data: false
```

And have host entries on all 3 master nodes.
But still getting following error. Kindly help.

> [2020-08-17T18:41:20,015][WARN
> ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [prod-elk-master2-new] master
> not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped
> (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes
> [prod-elk-master1-new, prod-elk-master2-new, prod-elk-master3-new] to
> bootstrap a cluster: have discovered
> [{prod-elk-master2-new}{1wrWU0LEQfiN-mUapeLtUg}{58SzXhJCQl6qS8J5bARnnw}{prod-elk-master2-new}{10.1.x.x:9300}{m}{xpack.installed=true}];
> discovery will continue using [10.1.x.x:9300, 10.1.x.x:9300] from
> hosts providers and
> [{prod-elk-master2-new}{1wrWU0LEQfiN-mUapeLtUg}{58SzXhJCQl6qS8J5bARnnw}{prod-elk-master2-new}{10.1.x.x:9300}{m}{xpack.installed=true}]
> from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in
> term 0

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the reason. My team member has enabled the firewall on the VMs and I must explicitly allow the ports 9200,9300.